# how can i remove a required option on close date(opportunity)

Tags: required-field

in my organization do not want use close date field also I can not hide this close date field, is there any alternate way to hide field or to change label name of close date field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mention you cannot hide the field but you can change the label like you asked.

Setup->Customize->Tab Names and Labels-> Rename Tabs and Labels

Click [Edit] next to opportunities then click [Next], you can rename the standard fields on the following screen.

Keep in mind that Close Date drives a lot of functionality in Salesforce and I would highly suggest you use the field for meaningful data even if you rename it.

Answer (score 6):

See this:

[Can I remove the required Close Date field in a new Opportunity?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004357&language=en_US)

> The standard "Close Date" field cannot be removed from any Opportunity
>   Page Layout, nor can the "Required" property be removed. You can check
>   which fields cannot be removed by going to the "edit" page of your
>   Opportunity page layout (using Enhanced Page Layout Editor), where
>   you'll see the fields denoted by a blue dot. You can also hover over
>   each and it will read "Always on layout."

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this for now, I have created VF page where I am not showing close date then with the extension I am populating this fields and on save I am displaying the close date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).